# Layout priority in Android

Tags: android

My program had two layout: layout1 and layout2.
I make the layout2 visible while layout1 is touched by OnTouchListener().
I want layout2 on the top of layot1.
On the contrary, layout2 is overridden by layout1.
Any one can help me to resolve the problem?
My code as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:visibility="invisible">


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/video_playback_pause"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_below="@id/relativeLayout2"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want relativeLayout2 to override videoView1.

Comment: Please provide a code / XML sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try FrameLayout using which you can make stack of Views.Also have a look at ViewFlipper.Also if you can place your layouts as fragments that also provide way to do this, depending on your requirements you can choose the best.